# How to check which dependency has errored while building a package?

Tags: julia

I am a new Julia user and am building my own package. When I build a package I created on my own I get this

```
(VFitApproximation) pkg> build VFitApproximation
    Building MathLink → `~/.julia/scratchspaces/44cfe95a-1eb2-52ea-b672-e2afdf69b78f/653c35640db592dfddd8c46dbb43d561cbef7862/build.log`
    Building Conda ───→ `~/.julia/scratchspaces/44cfe95a-1eb2-52ea-b672-e2afdf69b78f/299304989a5e6473d985212c28928899c74e9421/build.log`
    Building PyCall ──→ `~/.julia/scratchspaces/44cfe95a-1eb2-52ea-b672-e2afdf69b78f/169bb8ea6b1b143c5cf57df6d34d022a7b60c6db/build.log`
  Progress [========================================>]  4/4
  ✗ VFitApproximation
3 dependencies successfully precompiled in 9 seconds (38 already precompiled)
1 dependency errored
```

I don't know which dependency has errored and how to fix that. How do I ask Julia what has errored?

Comment: Perhaps try `build -v VFitApproximation` (verbose mode)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `VFitApproximation` itself that has the error (it's the only one with an ✗ next to it). You should try starting a session and typing `using VFitApproximation`; if that causes an error, the message will tell you much more about the origin than `build`. If that *doesn't* directly trigger an error, then you can try the verbose mode of `build` as suggested by @sundar above. Julia's package manager runs a lot of its system-wide operations in parallel, which is wonderful when you have to build dozens or hundreds of packages, but under those circumstances you only get general summaries rather than the level of detail you can get from operations focused on a single package.

More generally, most packages don't need manual `build`: it's typically used for packages that require special configuration at the time of installation. Examples might include downloading a data set from the internet (though this now better handled through [Artifacts](https://julialang.org/blog/2019/11/artifacts/)), or saving configuration data about the user's hardware to a file, etc. For reference, on my system, out of 418 packages I have `dev`ed, only 20 have `deps/build.jl` scripts, and many of those only because they haven't yet been updated to use Artifacts.

Bottom line: for most code, you never need `Pkg.build`, and you should just use `Pkg.precompile` or `using` directly.

Comment: Thank you! `using` package helped me identify my error which was in the module itself. There were some changes I made to the package that did not get revised (even though I was using Revise.jl),. Now that's a separate thing for me to figure out in my VSCode.

Thanks a lot for all your help!